# Check every Point around a Point in String 2d array

Tags: java, oop

I am currently making a battleships game in Java, and I am currently trying to set up the game rules so that a player cannot place a ship if it's to close to another. In this case, one grid.

I have a method that works for doing this, however it isn't very good.

This is my first method for adding my point in a Arraylist. I only want to use one `Point point = new Point(i, j);` and one `pointList.add(point);` and then check every other point around it like I do in point1 - point 8.

```
    public List<Point> addPoint(Point from, Point to) {
    for (int i = (int) from.getX(); i <= (int) to.getX(); i++) {
        for (int j = (int) from.getY(); j <= (int) to.getY(); j++) {
            Point point = new Point(i, j);
            Point point1 = new Point(i+1, j);
            Point point2 = new Point(i, j+1);
            Point point3 = new Point(i+1, j+1);
            Point point4 = new Point(i-1, j);
            Point point5 = new Point(i, j-1);
            Point point6 = new Point(i-1, j-1);
            Point point7 = new Point(i+1, j-1);
            Point point8 = new Point(i-1, j+1);
            pointList.add(point);
            pointList.add(point1);
            pointList.add(point2);
            pointList.add(point3);
            pointList.add(point4);
            pointList.add(point5);
            pointList.add(point6);
            pointList.add(point7);
            pointList.add(point8);
        }
    }
    return pointList;
}
```

And then run the `pointList.add(point);` through this method.

```
    public boolean isPointFreeForPlacement(Position position) {
    Point f = position.getFrom();
    Point t = position.getTo();
    for (Point p: pointList) {
        if (p.equals(f) || p.equals(t)) {
            System.out.println("Cannot place ships on top of another ship! Try again.");
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Does anyone know a smarter way of doing this?

Comment: use a 2d array to represent the battleship board instead of an array of points

Comment: Lookup "bounding box", it is quite easy to check if they are overlapping